# How to get the recently joined users from mysql table

Tags: php, sql

So I started my coding wit MYSQL and I have a table like following

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`school_division` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`email` text NOT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=32 ;
```

Now I want to show the recently joined students of a class in that class page. How can i do it? I tried the following.

```
"SELECT * FROM my_users WHERE school_division={$divsion} ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT 0 , 5";
```

But its listing only the first five students of the class. These students are the first joined users. How can I get the last 5 students who joined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `date` instead of `id`:

```
 "SELECT * FROM my_users WHERE school_division={$divsion} ORDER BY 'date' DESC LIMIT 0 , 5";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But its fetching the first five students of that batch who joined in the beginning. I want to fetch the recently joined students of that batch.

Comment: Well, you should ask @hakre for that one, he edited the post=) I would go for DESC

Comment: Sorry for the wrong feedback. Its working fine now. Thank you friends

Comment: @KristerAndersson: My fault ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sort descending by date:

`"SELECT * FROM my_users WHERE school_division={$divsion} ORDER BY 'date' DESC LIMIT 0 , 5";`

Answer (score 1):

The column `id` is an `auto_increment` column. Retrieving the last five users is thereby easily accomplished by quering for the last highest five values of that column. Explicitly ordering by the `date` column is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You should order by date instead of id, like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_users` WHERE `school_division`='".$divsion."' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 0 , 5"
```

Or, if you somehow must order on id...do an order by id ascending instead of descending.

Answer (score 0):

order by date not id

"SELECT * FROM my_users WHERE school_division={$divsion} ORDER BY 'date' DESC LIMIT 0 , 5";

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

not a semicolon